# Better way to achieve a common filter for different types of List

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am having two json arrays

One is of type Master & another is of Division master

I want to filter both the type and divison list

```
 <input [(ngModel)]="search">
 <li *ngFor="let type of divisonMaster| filterMaster : search">
```

Here I need to create two different filter since on is filtered using type desciption and other is filtered using division description.

sample for type filter

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { TypeMaster } from '../common/objectModels/type-master-model';
@Pipe({
  name: 'filterType'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[], searchText: string): any[] {
    if (!items) return [];
    if (!searchText) return items;
    searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();

      return items.filter(it => {
        return it.typeDescription.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
      });

  }
}
```

Is there a way I can achive this using a common filter.
One way to achieve this is using  instance of. But using instance of inside filter will cause performance I feel.

Any better way to achieve a common filter for different types of List.

Comment: You shouldn't use pipes to filter in the first place: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe

Comment: @JBNizet Then how to achieve this requirement ?

Comment: From the link I posted: *The Angular team and many experienced Angular developers strongly recommend moving filtering and sorting logic into the component itself. The component can expose a filteredHeroes or sortedHeroes property and take control over when and how often to execute the supporting logic. Any capabilities that you would have put in a pipe and shared across the app can be written in a filtering/sorting service and injected into the component.*